# How can I cache external API requests to the SQL database using Rails cache API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I'm just wondering how I can cache slow requests to external APIs in the database, as I do not want to maintain a memcache service, but I do want a distributed system that will work across multiple dynos and workers on heroku.

I can do it by building my own cache table, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way, especially one that works with the existing caching syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not to try Redis and wrap slow queries with **Rails.cache.fetch {}**?

Comment: Don't want to set up another server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache just about anything in Rails via a call to `Rails.cache.fetch`. You pass in a key for the cache to look up, and if there's a value in the cache (a "cache hit") then it will get used instead of your slow code.

Let's say we've got an API that takes two airport codes and a date, and returns the best price it can find. This can be a slow lookup, so it's a good candidate for caching:

```
def find_best_price(start_airport, end_airport, date)
  Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key_for(start_airport, end_airport, date)) do
    AirportPriceAPI.find_best_price(start_airport, end_airport, date)
  end
end

# Different routes & dates will have different prices, so we 
# need to have different cache keys for them.
def cache_key_for(start_airport, end_airport, date)
  "best_price:#{start_airport}:#{end_airport}:#{date}"
end
```

You can configure the data store for your cache in `config/application.rb` by [setting `config.cache_store`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#configuration). Rails has several kinds built in, but not all are suitable for Heroku. You can't use the `FileStore` because [dynos don't have persistent storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and it's not shared between dynos. `MemoryStore` isn't shared across dynos and will be wiped out if your dyno restarts.

Your best bet for Heroku is [the `MemCacheStore`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore). It's supported out-of-the-box in Rails, and Heroku [will give you 30Mb of memcache space for free](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/memcachedcloud). It's fast and perfect for use between multiple dynos.

But, if you did want to cache values in a database, you can provide your app with [a custom cache class](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#custom-cache-stores). All you have to do is [extend `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store) and be sure to implement `read`, `write`, `exist?`, `delete`, and `fetch`. And someone's [already packaged a DB-backed cache store as a gem](https://github.com/sergio-fry/activesupport-db-cache), so you don't even have to implement the low-level details yourself. :)

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you!